# How do I select an element with its name attribute in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get an element with its `name` attribute with jQuery?

Is there anything (like `#` for id and `.` for class) for name in jQuery?

Comment: I misunderstood your question to mean `tag names` as opposed to the `name` attribute, and proceeded to do backflips.

Answer (score 607, accepted):

```
$('[name="ElementNameHere"]').doStuff();
```

jQuery supports CSS3 style selectors, plus some more.

### See more

- **[jQuery - Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)**
- **[jQuery - `[attribute=""]` selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)**

Comment: More specific doc page: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: This is the best answer in the world. This site is stupid for not letting me award it with a bounty :(

Answer (score 36):

You can use:

```
jQuery('[name="' + nameAttributeValue + '"]');
```

this will be an inefficient way to select elements though, so it would be best to also use the tag name or restrict the search to a specific element:

```
jQuery('div[name="' + nameAttributeValue + '"]'); // with tag name
jQuery('div[name="' + nameAttributeValue + '"]',
     document.getElementById('searcharea'));      // with a search base
```

Comment: Selectors usually work from right to left, meaning regardless of elements, it would still search the name first, then the element. Hence your extended answer has little meat. But still, good answer :)

Comment: Quite right - it's the inclusion of the context that is more important, browsers without querySelectorAll or getElementsByName (special case for using the name attribute) would use getElementsByTagname('*') in sizzle making it better to use jQuery('#container').find('[name=someName]') than just jQuery('[name=someName]') - it might not be that important given browser support for getElementsByName though

Comment: How to get element by class?

Comment: Use `.classname` - examples can be found in the [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors)

Answer (score 30):

it's very simple getting a name:

```
$('[name=elementname]');
```

### Resource:

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-form-elements-by-name/ (google search: get element by name jQuery - first result)

Answer (score 16):

```
jQuery("[name='test']")
```

Although you should avoid it and if possible select by ID (e.g. `#myId`) as this has better performance because it invokes the native `getElementById`.

Comment: Yes, but that's not always possible... And as inferred from the question, OP already knows how to select by ID or classname.

Comment: I only want to point out that its heavier to use this kind of selectors.

Answer (score 10):

You could always do `$('input[name="somename"]')`

Comment: You could, but you would then miss the `select` and `textarea` elements.