# jQuery selector for name attribute?

Tags: jquery

Well, by assigning events or putting values or whatever we want to do to certain elements..

For ID we use:

```
$("#id").addClass("something");
```

For Class we use:

```
$(".class").addClass("something");
```

What about for **Name**?

Any help would be appreciated.

Can't find any certain solutions for this or I just didn't know the right words to search for haha.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I select an element with its name attribute in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680037/how-do-i-select-an-element-with-its-name-attribute-in-jquery)

Comment: Also have a look at the jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the generic selector for an attribute:

```
$("[name='xxx']")
```

jQuery reference here: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: You mean `$("[name='xxx']")` ?