# How to read value of element generated in php foreach

Tags: php, jquery

I have a piece of code where elements are generated in a for loop (PHP). The code is:

```
for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++)
{
  $member = $my_array[$i];
  <td><span id="myspan"><input type="text" id="username" value="<?php echo $member; ?>" /></span></td>
}
```

In my jquery code, I am trying to read the value of the clicked element but it is returning the value of the first element and not the value of the clicked element. I guess this is happening because the id of each element is the same. But then how to get the value of the clicked element?

My jQuery code is:

```
$("#myspan").click(function(){
alert(username);
});
```

Any pointers will be much appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change id to name `<span name="myspan$i">` and [get your span by name like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680037/how-do-i-select-an-element-with-its-name-attribute-in-jquery). finally move your click code inside for loop

```
for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++)
{
  $member = $my_array[$i];
  <td><span name="myspan"><input type="text" id="username" value="<?php echo $member; ?>" /></span></td>

$('[name="myspan$i"]').click(function(){
    YOUR CODE
});
}
```

Comment: `name` attribute on spans is definitely not valid HTML.

Comment: sort of in the right direction. Basically all I had to do was to move the code inside the for loop and append each identifier with a <?php echo $I; ?>. That did the job. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving each element the same id, give them all the same class, e.g.

```
<span class="myspan" ...> ... </span>
```

Then target the elements by class instead of by id with jQuery, like:

```
$('myspan').click(function (event) {
    var input = $(event.target).find("input");
    alert(input.val());
}
```

Comment: Try debugging? Or uploading a jsfiddle or something would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

Move the jQuery code inside the for loop and append each identifier with  echo $I;